# Create table via PHP + HTML by selecting data from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I have stored values in some *MySQL* tables. I need to select them and pass in *HTML* table via *PHP*. *HTML* table should look like in image below:

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

[image: sample table]

**CODE**

I'm using following code:

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <th>First Name </th> //There are headers shown in image     
        <th>Middle Name</th>            
        <th>Last Name </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Rank </th>              
        <th>Rank Applied </th> 
        <th>Date Applied </th> 
        <th>Date Availability </th>     
        <th>Vessels Type </th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>DOB </th>               
        <th>POB </th>               
        <th>Nationality </th>       
        <th>English </th> 
    </tr>
........

<?php 
while ($users->fetch()) { 
?>
<tr>        
    <td><?php echo $FirstName; ?></td> // there are variables selected from MySQL tables            
    <td><?php echo $MiddleName; ?></td>             
    <td><?php echo $LastName; ?></td>               
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $Rank; ?></td>               
    <td><?php echo $RankApplied; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $DateAvailability; ?></td>   
    <td><?php echo $VesselsType; ?></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $DOB; ?></td>                
    <td><?php echo $POB; ?></td>                
    <td><?php echo $Nationality; ?></td>        
    <td><?php echo $English; ?></td> 
</tr>
........
<?php 
} 
?>
</table>
```

**WRONG OUTPUT FOR NOW**

I don't know how to achieve table's structure like in image above. For now I have structure like:

```
// All headers going here.....
First Name   Middle Name   Last Name
Rank   Rank Applied     Date Availability   VesselsType
DOB    POB     Nationality     English
............
// All values below headers....
John   -   Anderson
foo@bar.com   5545565445
Something 1   Something 2   Something 3
...........
```

As you see in sample, first printed all headers and after It going all values, but each header should be upper the value.

I don't know If It's wrong structure of *HTML* table or maybe something wrong with *PHP* loop, or should I do something with *CSS*...? Have you any ideas? If something unclear - ask me and I'll provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Move the entire form structure into your loop since you want a new table every loop:

```
<?php 
while ($users->fetch()) { 
?>
<table>
<tr> 
    <th>First Name </th> //There are headers shown in image     
    <th>Middle Name</th>            
    <th>Last Name </th>
</tr>
<tr>        
    <td><?php echo $FirstName; ?></td> // there are variables selected from MySQL tables            
    <td><?php echo $MiddleName; ?></td>             
    <td><?php echo $LastName; ?></td>               
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Rank </th>              
    <th>Rank Applied </th> 
    <th>Date Applied </th> 
    <th>Date Availability </th>     
    <th>Vessels Type </th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $Rank; ?></td>               
    <td><?php echo $RankApplied; ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $DateAvailability; ?></td>   
    <td><?php echo $VesselsType; ?></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>DOB </th>               
    <th>POB </th>               
    <th>Nationality </th>       
    <th>English </th> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $DOB; ?></td>                
    <td><?php echo $POB; ?></td>                
    <td><?php echo $Nationality; ?></td>        
    <td><?php echo $English; ?></td> 
</tr>
</table>
<?php 
} 
?>
```